# Current Url is not correct for google calendar api

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

When I sent an authsub request, google says the url is not correct.
I'm suspecting this is because I have a subdomain in my url.

The url that sends the request is http://admin.domain.com/test.php

In php, I put this line of code in the $next variable : '

```
http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

When I echo it, it shows the proper url but google tells me this :

The page you have requested cannot be displayed. Another site was
requesting access to your Google Account, but sent a malformed
request. Please contact the site that you were trying to use when you
received this message to inform them of the error. A detailed error
message follows:

> The page you have requested cannot be displayed. Another site was requesting access to your Google Account, but sent a malformed request. Please contact the site that you were trying to use when you received this message to inform them of the error.
>
> A detailed error message follows:  The site "http://domain.com" has not been registered.

Where is my problem ?

Thanks,

Etienne NOEL

EDIT1:

Here's my code: I followed all the instructions and the error still remains:

```
session_start();

require_once 'lib/Zend/Loader.php';
set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/');

    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');


$my_calendar = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full';

if (!isset($_SESSION['cal_token'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['token'])) {
        // You can convert the single-use token to a session token.
        $session_token =
            Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken($_GET['token']);
        // Store the session token in our session.
        $_SESSION['cal_token'] = $session_token;
    } else {
        // Display link to generate single-use token
        $googleUri = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubTokenUri(
            'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
            $my_calendar, 0, 1);
        echo "Click <a href='$googleUri'>here</a> " .
             "to authorize this application.";
        exit();
    }
}

// Create an authenticated HTTP Client to talk to Google.
$client = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getHttpClient($_SESSION['cal_token']);

// Create a Gdata object using the authenticated Http Client
$cal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
```

Comment: try `Zend_Debug::dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` to see what is being sent.

Comment: the zend_debug isn't included in the zend package it seems. What do I have to include for it to be loaded.

Comment: It is included. Do you have your environment set up properly? Try `include "Zend/Debug"`. Alternatively `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` may work

Comment: I tried include "Zend/debug" but it's not found.  I also tried the following code: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html with the same error from google...

Comment: I think your Zend Framework environment is not set up correctly http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html Also that should be "Zend/Debug", note the uppercase D, yours was lowercase.

Comment: Here is what I did:  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/Zend/Loader.php';        //We Load all the Zend components
  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');

Comment: Do I do Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Debug') or include ("Zend/Debug") either way, it said it couldn't find the Debug class.

Comment: I think you need to follow the quick start I linked above. When you have your Zend Framework working come back.

Comment: I added my code. I followed the instructions.

Comment: @CoachNono: How did you solved this issue. I have same issue

Comment: @gowri I really don't remember but post a question and I'll try to answer it.